# Can I use wcsession to make the parent iOS app go to foreground

Tags: objective-c, background, watchkit, foreground, watchos-2

I have successfully made it possible for exchanging data between the watch and the phone by making use of `WCSession`.
However, the problem I find is that the parent app will not automatically go to foreground when it receives a message.
Is there a way to make it happen? Because I saw some watch app able to awake their parent apps.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apps can't bring themselves to the foreground. Is not possible.

Comment: I successfully get data from watchapp but when ios app open i want to display that data in controller do some operation on that data

How I get notified that i get watchapp data aprat from this didReceiveMessage method

Answer (score 2):

Using WCSession's sendMessage API the watch extension can wake the iOS app up in the background when session.reachable is true. You cannot wake the iOS app up in the foreground from the watch extension, but you can get your iOS app to start location tracking, play background audio, etc.